# If I want to use java to implement offline signature, where can I find the information?

Tags: address

Where is the process of iota private key, address generation and signature?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the java binding for the rust client:

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/java

Then you make a Client object, then run the function `Client.get_addresses()`. Also in the [docs.iota.org](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/python/examples.html) it reccomends to use stronghold for and account type ownership for security.

> We strongly recommend to use official wallet.rs library together with stronghold.rs enclave for value-based transfers. This combination incorporates the best security practices while dealing with seeds, related addresses and UTXO.

IOTA uses the [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) and [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) standard. Here is a python example, the functions in java should have the same names,

```
import os import iota_client # Get the seed from environment variableIOTA_SEED_SECRET = os.getenv('IOTA_SEED_SECRET') if not IOTA_SEED_SECRET: raise Exception("Please define environment variable called `IOTA_SEED_SECRET`") client = iota_client.Client() address_changed_list = client.get_addresses( seed=IOTA_SEED_SECRET, account_index=0, input_range_begin=0, input_range_end=10, get_all=True ) print(address_changed_list)
```